# Convert Json results into HTML form using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: json, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to display the balance related to a specific card when the Id is being selected from the dropdown select list and show the balance value in [enter image description here][1]input on a form.

But what I am getting is only the JSON results when I am running the program. my form is not appearing

The Test action in the controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var data = from als in ctx.TbIstanbulCards select new { als.IstanbulCardId, als.Balance };
    return Json(data.ToList());
}
```

The `Index` view (Test)

```
@model VmIstanbul

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/Customer?handler=SelectAll";
            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (element) {
                    $("#customerid").append("<option>
        "
        + element.IstanbulCardId + "
    </option > ");
            });
            };
            options.error = function () {
                $("#msg").html("Error while
    making Ajax call!");
        };
            $.ajax(options);
        });

        $("#customerid").change(function () {
            var options = {};
            options.url = "/Customer/" +
                $("#customerid").val() + "?handler=SelectByID";
            options.type = "GET";
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.success = function (data) {
                $("#companyname").val(data.Balance);
                //$("#contactname").val(data.contactName);
                //$("#country").val(data.country);
            };
            options.error = function () {
                $("#msg").html("Error while making Ajax call!");
            };
            $.ajax(options);
        });


</script>

}
<form id="myForm" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Test">
    <label for="departmentsDropdown"><b>Card</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" onchange="getValue()" id="departmentsDropdown" name="departmentsDropdown"></select><br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="show" />
</form>
```

The result appear like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqDVl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your codes, since the ajax url is razor page route but not mvc. Do you enable both of them?

Besides, from your previous post I see that the View name is `Test.cshtml`, while the `Test` action return Json, so when you access `/Custom/Test`, you just get the Json results instead of a View.

If the Test action is used to display the html view, I think it should return View:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Update:**

Have an action(Test) to return View(Test.cshtml). Just `reutn View()` without any data since I didn't see any place you use the model(VmIstanbul) value in your view.

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    
    return View();
}
```

Have another action to return data to ajax, Give it a name except `Test`. For example:

```
public IActionResult TestSelect()
{
    var data = from als in ctx.TbIstanbulCards select new { als.IstanbulCardId, als.Balance };
    return Json(data.ToList());
}
```

And change the ajax url to `TestSelect`

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Customer/TestSelect",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Card id</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        s += '<option value="' + data[i].balance + '">' + data[i].istanbulCardId + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#departmentsDropdown").html(s);
                }
            })
        })

        function getValue() {
            var myVal = $("#departmentsDropdown").val();
            $("#show").val(myVal);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i tried to convert the return controller to view but I got (undefined) in m select and input HTML 
Do you have any idea how can I solve it please?

Comment: Hi @ALAAELDIN, which is undefined, could you show us the detail error messages. Also, it may be helpful if you can share the code code of `SelectAll` method.

Comment: Hi @mj1313 i wanted to share with you the problem as a video but I didn't know how to upload it so could you click on (here is my problem ) and see it please I made it as gif photo    ![here is my problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wKXbTCTnsCLsbBRjoT9N9QZaKmKGlE2/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hi @ALAAELDIN, I have no access to your link, I think it is more convenient to share your project on github.

Comment: Hi @mj1313   Could you try again I've given you access please?        ![here is my problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wKXbTCTnsCLsbBRjoT9N9QZaKmKGlE2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ALAAELDIN, It seems you want the `Test()` method to return value and append them to select list. while you also want the Test.cshtml as view, so the problem occurs. In this case, you need to separate them. See my update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel frustrated with this problem that took me more than 10 days. I hope that you will help me in solving this problem. I have uploaded the entire project to the drive and shared it with you ..    ![Here Is My Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IRy-UsaGzF5bZJu1tjKAyGSxZP7TkaML/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @ALAAELDIN, I have download your project and test it. The returned data in ajax the first letter should be lowercase. '<option value="' + data[i].balance + '">' + data[i].istanbulCardId + '</option>'. And you missed a `})` in `document.ready` function. I have modified them. You can see the test result.

Comment: Hi @mj1313  I want to thank you so much for helping me all this time. The problem has already been resolved as you suggested